# Wireguard Site-to-Site connection in Docker ping working but TCP not

Tags: vpn, docker, routing, port-forwarding, wireguard

I am quite desperate. I am trying to get my site-to-site vpn setup working, but no luck so far. Please don't judge me, I am quite new to the routing problematic.
I have a VPS with a public IP 123.456.789 and on there a docker stack running with the [linuxserver swag](https://docs.linuxserver.io/general/swag) container and some other containers. Because I don't have a IPv4 Address at my home network just a DS-Lite connection from my ISP I want to connect to the server via a wireguard VPN to have all my services available behind the swag container.
Additionally it would be beneficial when I can down the line add some more client who can all access my home network.

I am using the [linuxserver wireguard](https://docs.linuxserver.io/images/docker-wireguard) container both as server and client with the compose files:

Server side

```
version: "3"

services:

  # WireGuard VPN service
  wireguard:
    image: linuxserver/wireguard:latest
    container_name: wireguard
    networks:
      swag-network:
        ipv4_address: 172.19.0.10
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - SYS_MODULE
    volumes:
      - ./config:/config
    ports:
      # Port of the WireGuard VPN server
      - "51820:51820/udp"
    environment:
      - PUID=1001
      - PGID=1001
      - TZ=Europe/Amsterdam
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
    restart: unless-stopped

  # WireGuard-UI service
  wireguard-ui:
    image: ngoduykhanh/wireguard-ui:latest
    container_name: wireguard-ui
    depends_on:
      - wireguard
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    # Use the network of the 'wireguard' service
    # This enables to show active clients in the status page
    network_mode: service:wireguard
    environment:
      - SENDGRID_API_KEY
      - EMAIL_FROM_ADDRESS
      - EMAIL_FROM_NAME
      - SESSION_SECRET
      - WGUI_USERNAME=${wgui_username}
      - WGUI_PASSWORD=${wgui_password}
      - WG_CONF_TEMPLATE
      - WGUI_MANAGE_START=true
      - WGUI_MANAGE_RESTART=true
    logging:
      driver: json-file
      options:
        max-size: 50m
    volumes:
      - ./db:/app/db
      - ./config:/etc/wireguard
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  swag-network:
    external: true
```

and the wg0.conf

```
# This file was generated using wireguard-ui (https://github.com/ngoduykhanh/wireguard-ui)
# Please don't modify it manually, otherwise your change might get replaced.

# Address updated at:     2023-07-09 07:59:28.178966655 +0000 UTC
# Private Key updated at: 2023-07-09 07:44:46.69833353 +0000 UTC
[Interface]
Address = 10.21.2.0/24
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = *secret*
DNS = 1.1.1.1
MTU = 1450

#PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT
#PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostUP = iptables -A FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
#PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o %i -j MASQUERADE
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

#PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT
#PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
#PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o %i -j MASQUERADE
PostUp = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

Table = auto

[Peer]
PublicKey = *secret*
PresharedKey = *secret*
AllowedIPs = 10.21.2.0/24,10.21.0.0/23
```

and on the client side

```
version: "3"

services:
  wireguard:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/wireguard:latest
    container_name: wireguard
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - SYS_MODULE
    environment:
      - PUID=1001
      - PGID=1001
      - TZ=Europe/Amsterdam
    volumes:
      - ./config:/config
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
      - net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  default:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.18.7.0/24
          gateway: 172.18.7.1
```

with the wg0.conf

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.21.2.1/32
PrivateKey = *secret*
DNS = 1.1.1.1
MTU = 1450

#PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT
#PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostUP = iptables -A FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
#PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg0 -j MASQUERADE
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

#PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT
#PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
#PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o wg0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
PublicKey = *secret*
PresharedKey = *secret*
AllowedIPs = 10.21.2.0/32,172.19.0.0/16
Endpoint = 123.456.789:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

With this configuration and on the server side a

```
ip route add 10.21.0.0/23 via 172.19.0.10
```

Same for the Client side. I added a static route inside my router at home and added a similar route on my client machine to the vpn.

I can ping both inside the swag container and outside on the server host my local network for example with `ping 10.21.0.10`and `docker exec swag ping 10.21.0.10` both work. But when I not try to reverse proxy to a service I get timed out. I also tried the commands

```
docker exec swag nc -vz 10.21.0.10 8443
Connection to 10.21.0.10 8443 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

but from the host I got

```
nc -vz 10.21.0.10 8443
10.21.0.10: inverse host lookup failed: Unknown host
(UNKNOWN) [10.21.0.10] 8443 (?) open
```

As you can see in the config files I tried a little bit with iptable configurations but no luck. I think its some kind of routing problem.

---

So in summary:

|  | Home Network | Server Network |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Public IP | N/A | 123.456.789 |
| Private Subnet | 10.21.0.0/23 | N/A |
| Private IP | 10.21.0.10 | N/A |
| Docker Subnet | 172.18.7.0/24 | 172.19.0.0/24 |
| Docker IP | 172.18.7.10 | 172.19.0.10 |
| VPN IP | 10.21.2.1 | 10.21.0.0 |

With the configuration above pinging every client inside both networks from both networks functions but TCP services like SSH, HTTP, HTTPS are not working.